# Convert url() call to string

Tags: stylus

I am trying to write transparent background-image mixin for retina images, however, I got stuck because Stylus treats url() as call and does not allow any string manipulation.

Base of the mixin:

```
background-image($file, $retina = false)
  if $retina == "2x"
    $path = pathjoin(dirname($file), basename($file, extname($file)) + '@2x' + extname($file))
    background-image: unquote($path)
  else
    background-image: $file
```

Which means this works

```
.foo {
  background-image: "url(img/man-with-tablet.jpg)" 2x;
}
```

but I would like to have clean CSS syntax:

```
.foo {
  background-image: url(img/man-with-tablet.jpg) 2x;
}
```

which results into error *TypeError: expected string, ident or literal, but got call:url(img / man-with-tablet . jpg)*

Is there any way how to convert $file from url() call to string? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can coerce this call to string (by concatenating it with `''`). But in this case, you need to wrap the arguments of `url()` call into quotes.

```
background-image($file, $retina = false)
  if $retina == "2x"
    $file = '' + $file
    $path = pathjoin(dirname($file), basename($file, extname($file)) + '@2x' + extname($file))
    background-image: unquote($path)
  else
    background-image: $file

.foo {
  background-image: url('img/man-with-tablet.jpg') 2x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Btw. works even without quotes, but in that case, there are extra white-spaces present in the output. Interesting (and pretty badly designed) is that if you swap operands, it does not work.